# Different quotient of $f(x,y,z,h) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u/2}(h+u)\frac{3x(h+u+z)}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+(h+u+z)^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}du$ with respect to $h$

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have to compute the limit of the difference quotient of the function $f(x,y,z,h)$ defined as:
$f(x,y,z,h) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u/2}(h+u)\frac{3x(h+u+z)}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+(h+u+z)^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}du$

i have to take the limit of the difference quotient with respect to $h$ that is to say:
$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(x,y,z,h+\epsilon)-f(x,y,z,h)}{\epsilon}$

that should be similar to a differentiation, however i'm not confident with differentiation of function defined by integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following technique.
If $$H(x)=\int^{b}_{a}h(x,y)\,dy\Rightarrow \frac{dH}{dx}=\int^{b}_{a}\frac{\partial{h(x,y)}}{\partial{x}}\,dy$$

Comment: are you sure that i can simply derive under the sign of integral?

Comment: This is Leibniz rule. for details look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: then i just have to take the derivative of $e^{-u/2}(h+u)\frac{3x(h+u+z)}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+(h+u+z)^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}$ with respect to $h$? that looks pretty straightforward...

Comment: Yes, basically you differentiate the integrand with respect to your variable $h$.